# NAT between 2 LAN interfaces in Opnsense?

Tags: firewall, nat, vlan, opnsense

I'm not a network pro so some of my terminology may be off. I've tried to explain what I'm trying to achieve in different ways to hopefully make my request more understandable.

I have Opnsense running on a mini-computer with four 1Gb ports and two 10Gb ports. One 10Gb port has been configured as my WAN interface which connects to 10Gb port on my ISP-provided modem/router. The other 10Gb/s port is my LAN1 interface (with DCHP server enabled). The LAN1 physical port leads to a 10Gb port on a managed switch which also has mesh access wifi plugged in.

I've segmented the switch into multiple untagged VLANs. I've also set up another Interface (LAN2) in Opnsense with a different IP range (also with DHCP serve). LAN2 uses one of the 1gb/s physical ports on firewall which plugs into the switch but on VLAN2 which also has  different access points plugged in.

At the moment LAN1 cannot communicate with LAN2. I would like LAN1 to be able to access IoT devices on LAN2 but LAN2 not be able to access LAN1. Or put another way create a sort of virtual router between the two LANs (also making sure each LAN's DHCP server does not interfere with the other) Another requirement is that I don't lose the 10gb/s network speed of wired devices on my lAN1.(i.e. LAN1 only slows down to 1Gb when I try to access 1Gb devices LAN2)

A walkthrough of my desired state put another way:

WAN interface (10Gb physical port) has an ip from my ISP's router (192.168.1.x range)
LAN1 can access the Internet via 10Gb WAN port (192.168.2.x devices)
LAN1 10Gb port physically connected to VLAN1 segment of switch (safe LAN computers)
LAN2 physical 1Gb port (102.168.3.x range) connected to VLAN2 segment of the switch (unsafe IoT devices)
LAN1 can ping LAN2 devices (192.168.3.x range)
LAN2 cannot ping LAN1 but can still access the internet
LAN1 can download from the internet at 10Gb (i.e. it doesn't slow down to 1Gb)

Comment: Why do you want NAT? Configure firewall rules to achieve what you want!

Comment: As mentioned, my terminology may be off. Do you know how I would do that to match my requirements for LAN1 and LAN2?

Answer (score 0):

> At the moment LAN1 cannot communicate with LAN2. I would like LAN1 to be able to access IoT devices on LAN2 but LAN2 not be able to access LAN1. Or put another way create a sort of virtual router between the two LANs

You don't need a virtual router. You *have* a router there: OPNsense.

As long as opnsense is set as default gateway for your networks, and firewall rules are configured to allow traffic, it will forward traffic just fine.

Note that default for most firewalls (and OPNSense) is deny, so you need rules to *allow* traffic. Furthermore, note that it's a stateful firewall, so return traffic for the same tcp session will generally be permitted.

Comment: Do you know where specifically would I go in Opnsense settings to change firewall rules for LAN1 and LAN2? And What exactly should I change them to get the behavior I'm looking for?

Comment: Hire a networking professional. OPNSense is *very* straight forward, and if you don't have enough knowledge to do this task you don't know enough to do networking.

Comment: I thought the purpose of StackExchange was to answer these sorts of questions. Am I mistaken and it has some other purpose?

Comment: Serverfault is a site for professionals. It's not for providing learning materials. This is *basic* networking. I would suggest reading the manual, and perhaps a book on how TCP/IP works. It's not a ten line answer.

Comment: I have a basic understanding of how TCP/IP works. II have used ufw in lUbuntu  j'am just not familiar with how the firewall rules work specifically in OPNSense as its more involved.. If the answer is too long and you don't want to answer I understand. Thanks for the reply

Comment: They work more or less the same way. You need to allow traffic, where the originating interface is the source of the connection.